# How to test dependent Django API endpoints in isolation?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm working on a Django project with two API endpoints that operate in tandem. Here's the flow:

1. The first API endpoint modifies some data, or maybe creates new records, and then it returns certain information.
2. This returned information from the first API is then used as input to call the second API endpoint.

I've been able to write a test for the first API endpoint without any issues. However, when it comes to the second API endpoint, I'm at a crossroads:

- Should I call the first API within the test of the second API to get the required information? (This feels like it's breaking the isolation principle of testing.)
- Or, should I replicate the state or environment using fixtures/mocks so that I can directly test the second API without the actual call to the first API?

I'd appreciate insights on the best practices for this scenario. Is there a standard or recommended way of handling such situations in Django testing?